# Sort function of javascript is not working as desired

Tags: javascript

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
    myarray = new Array();
    myarray[0] = parseInt("30");
    myarray[1] = parseInt("32");
    myarray[2] = parseInt("6");
    myarray.sort();
    document.write (myarray[0] + "," + myarray[1] + "," + myarray[2] + "<br/>");
    myarray.reverse();
    document.write (myarray[0] + "," + myarray[1] + "," + myarray[2]);
```

The above code will output like this :

```
  30,32,6
  6,32,30
```

But I want it like this :

```
6,30,32
32,30,6
```

How can I achieve this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: myarray.sort(function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
    });... will give you 6,30,32

Comment: myarray.sort(function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}).reverse(); will give you the reverse one..

Comment: [JavaScript sort() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: I suppose you've provide a simplified version of your _real_ code, but why would you use `=parseInt("30");` instead of `=30;`? (If your real code is dealing with user-input data you _must_ provide a radix to `parseInt()` as in `parseInt("30",10)`.) By the way, did it occur to you to look at [some `.sort()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) before posting this question?

Answer (score 2):

Sort is done alphabetically by default.

Use:

```
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

Instead

Answer (score 1):

```
myarray.sort(function compareNumbers(a, b) {
return a - b;
});
```

will give you [6, 30, 32], and

```
myarray.sort(function compareNumbers(a, b) {
return b -a;
});
```

will give you the reverse

Answer (score 0):

**Array.sort**

If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in lexicographic ("dictionary" or "telephone book," not numerical) order.

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

numberArray.sort(compareNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

For numeric arrays try this:

**Ascending Sorting:**

```
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

**Descending Sorting:**

```
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort numbers, please use the following:

```
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

Please see this for more details on sorting alphabets/numbers:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp